# 100% classification accuracy

Tags: deep-learning, cross-validation, multilabel-classification

I am trying to perform a multi-class classification where the network is trained to classify objects into 3 categories: cars, pedestrians and miscellaneous. I am using the [KITTI Dataset](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/raw_data.php) for car instances and [Freiburg University's Polyterrasse Dataset](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~spinello/pcloud-dataset.html)  for pedestrian instances. ModelNet40 is being used for miscellaneous.

I am using equal number of samples for all three classes as the overall data and they have been divided into 7:3 ratio. Upon training for 75epochs, when I evaluate, the network is giving me 100% accurate classification in both miscellaneous and cars and 99.5% accurate classification in pedestrians. I am not sure if these numbers are valid. I checked the softmax values for the predictions and the network seems very confident in each classification. Around 0.98 softmax values for the predictions. I also checked the tensorboard plot for accuracy and loss and the curves stagnant after hitting a peak. Does this mean the network is overtrained or overfitting? Have I made a mistake somewhere? To me, the numbers seem unrealistic. How else can I cross-validate my results? 
[Loss Tensorboard plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg8AW.png) 
[image: Accuracy Plot]

Other important links: [PointNet implementation Github Repo](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet)